# No CSS with cakePHP installed in subfolder of server

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I'm facing a problem with a cakephp application.

On my server, I have a folder called DIGIPRESSKIT (this folder is used by the domain www.digipresskit-online.com), I placed all the cake's folders into it and when I load the page, there is no CSS, like cake can't access my webroot.
Is there any chance u check my .htaccess ?
I read lots of forums about that, and here is what they tell me to do :

Code: "root/.htaccess" (/DIGIPRESSKIT)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Code: "root/app/.htaccess" (/DIGIPRESSKIT/app)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /webroot/$1 [L]
```

Code: "root/app/webroot/.htaccess"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can have many domains on this host, you can try this solution:

.htaccess on servers root (/)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} digipresskit-online.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/DIGIPRESSKIT
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ one/$1 [L]

RewriteRule    ^$ /    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) /$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess on subfolder (/DIGIPRESSKIT)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

DIGIPRESSKIT/app and DIGIPRESSKIT/app/webroot/ no change